# How do you use the for loop in this code?

Tags: string, loops, for-loop, binary

```
def binary_string(s):
```

Write a function that takes a string, converts it to a binary string
     where vowels are replaced by 0 and consonants are replaced by 1.
     The function should return the binary string.

> > > binary_string("Karen")
> > >            '10101'
> > >       binary_string("Hello World!")
> > >            '10110 10111!'

```
if __name__ == '__main__':     
import doctest     
doctest.testmod(verbose = True)
```

Comment: You should add an appropriate tag to identify what language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Assuming the name of your string variable is "stringVar".

```
string binaryString="";
for(int i=0;i<stringVar.Length();i++)
{
    if(stringVar == 'a' || stringVar == 'A' || stringVar == 'e') //and so on
    {
        binaryString[i] = '0';
    }
    else
    {
        binaryString[i] = '1';
    }
}//end for loop.
print(binaryString);
```

This should give you the result you are looking for. This is the basic functionality. The rest depends on the language you are coding in.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified language in which you want solution, so i am assuming it to be java(from my side ). Although, algorithm will be valid for all languages.
**code**

```
public class SO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Karen";
        char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : arr) {

            if(Character.isAlphabetic(c)){
                if (isVowel(c)) {
                    binary.append("0");
                }else{
                    binary.append("1");
                }
            }else{
                binary.append(c);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(binary);
    }

    private static boolean isVowel(char c) {
        if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' || c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**output**

```
When input is 
String s = "Karen";
then output is
binary = 10101
```

and

```
When input is 
String s = "Hello World!";
then output is
binary = 10110 10111!
```